# Apply animation to the last element li:after that contains background color #a1c642

Tags: html, sass

I need to apply `@roll` animation in the last `li:after` element that contains `background-color: #a1c642`. How can i do this?

```css
@-moz-keyframes roll {
 0% { width:0; }
  100% { width:100%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes roll {
 0% { width:0; }
  100% { width:100%; }
}

.multi-steps > li.is-active:before, .multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:before {
    content: counter(stepNum);
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active:after, .multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:after {
    background-color: #ededed;
  }

  .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista:before, .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista ~ li:before {
    content: counter(stepNum);
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista:after, .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista ~ li:after {
    background-color: #ededed;
  }
  
  .multi-steps {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .multi-steps > li {
    counter-increment: stepNum;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    color: #a1c642;
    z-index:99!important;
    
  }

  .multi-steps > li.is-active {
    color: #a1c642!important;
    
  }

  .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista {
    color: darkorange!important;
  }

  .multi-steps > li:before {
    content: '\f00c';
    content: '\2713;';
    content: '\10003';
    content: '\10004';
    content: '\2713';
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #a1c642;
    border-radius: 50%;

  }
  .multi-steps > li:after {
    content: '';
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #a1c642;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .multi-steps > li:last-child:after {
    display: none;
    
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista:before {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: darkorange;
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active:before {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #a1c642;;
    
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li {
    color: #808080;
    
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:before {
    background-color: #ededed;
    border-color: #ededed;
    
  }

  .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista ~ li {
    color: #808080;
  }
  .multi-steps > li.is-active-acao-lojista ~ li:before {
    background-color: #ededed;
    border-color: #ededed;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled multi-steps">
  <li>Pedido recebido</li>
  <li class="is-active">Pagamento aprovado</li>
  <li class="is-active-acao-lojista">Faturar pedido</li>
  <li class="is-active-acao-lojista">Enviar dados rastreio</li>
  <li>Confirmar entrega</li>
</ul>
```

I try something like:

```
.multi-steps > li:after:last-child{
      animation-name: roll;
      animation-duration: 5s;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
```

Also tried:

```
  .multi-steps > li::after:nth-last-child(2){
    animation-name: roll;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: what exactly do you want? Please provide clean and comprehensible description of your problem.

Comment: I need to apply the roll animation in the penultimate .multi-steps > li:after

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not possible with CSS alone. Either you need JavaScript to calculate, which is the first-element after the last `.is-active` element, or you change the HTML code so that it adds a new class name like `last`

Answer (score 0):

Just try to change "li::after:nth-last-child(2)" to "li:nth-child(2)::after". What you are writing is wrong. You cannot select a last child and a nth at the same time.

Keep in mind that the child selector is applied to the li itself. So it should come right after it. Then, you can select the pseudo element that is inside the li child you wanted to stylize.